# How to share a variable between functions in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
public function showcart() { 
$showcartdata = array();
$showcartdata['showcart'] = $this->ShowcartModel->showcart_mod();

$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('showcart_view.php',$showcartdata);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

public function place_order() { 
$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('placeorder_onsubmit.php',$showcartdata);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

I have looked all over to find a way to share the variable  in the first method "$showcartdata['showcart']" with the methods below to be used in a view file. I tried to use Global variable but in vain. Is there any smart way to accomplish the this task. Thanks a lot for the help and your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your variable in controller's `constructor` as below.Then it is accessible from all controller's functions.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $showcartdata = array();
    $showcartdata['showcart'] = $this->ShowcartModel->showcart_mod();
}
public function showcart() { 
$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('showcart_view.php',$showcartdata);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

public function place_order() { 
$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('placeorder_onsubmit.php',$showcartdata);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Himat. I did what you advised before I read ur comment. Mere word of thanks is not enough. Good day

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is using **GLOBALS**

```
$_GLOBALS['global_var'] = 'Some Shareable Data';

function func1()
{
    $x = $_GLOBALS['global_var'];
    //function codes
}
```

Another way is using **ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES**
  To know more visit [this](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) and [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjC8raW2dLRAhXC2RoKHWmEANEQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Freserved.variables.environment.php&usg=AFQjCNH_p6WmGlJnMfa9D7cgUBQgX5wulw&sig2=umZ17JYzUFEtdXg6x1EqHg)

Also if the value is static you can define **CONSTANTS**

```
define('MY_CONST', 'static data');

function func1()
{
    $x = MY_CONST;
    function codes
}
```